# show div dynamically when user entered number in a textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have textbox with an id `#txtUserEntry` where user can put the number of their family member living in their house and a button `#btnAddOccupant` to click after they put a number in textbox and `#divOccupantProfile` should show up depends on the number entered so it means 1 family member is equal to 1 `#divOccupantProfile`

aspx code

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left"><asp:Label ID="lbUserEntry" runat="server" Text="Number of House occupant"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUserEntry" class="basetxt" runat="server" Width="290"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left"><asp:Button ID="btnAddOccupant" runat="server" Text="+" />
    <asp:Label ID="lbres5" runat="server" Text="Add Occupant"></asp:Label></td>
 </tr>
```

divOccupantProfile

```
<div id="divOccupantProfile">

<asp:Label ID="OPfamilyname" runat="server" Text="Family Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="textOPfamilyname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPfirstname" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="textOPfirstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPmiddlename" runat="server" Text="Middle Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="textOPmiddlename" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPmaritalstatus" runat="server" Text="Marital Status"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOPmaritalstatus" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Married</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Single</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Divorced</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPoccupation" runat="server" Text="Occupation"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="textOPoccupation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPrelationship" runat="server" Text="Relationship"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOPrelationship" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Wife</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Daughter</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Son</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Father</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Mother</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>House helper</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Driver</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>

 </div>
```

can someone show me an example how to do this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
$('#btnAddOccupant').click(function(){
        var occupants = $('#txtUserEntry').val();
        //here some check on occupants.....

        for(int i = 0;i<occupants;i++){
            $(somewhere).append($('#divOccupantProfile').html());
        }
    })
```

Some suggestions:
because you are going to use multiple divOccupantProfile, it's better to use selectors based on the class instead of ID, otherwise in your page you'll have 1+ elements with the same ID.

The     $(somewhere)
is the "container" where you want to put all the div related to each occupant profile

Also note that the .html() function will copy the html INSIDE the div, exluding the div itself. So if you want to have N elements formed in this way

```
<div class="occupantProfile">...</div>
<div class="occupantProfile">...</div>
```

you have to use

```
somewhere.append($('<div').append($('.occupantProfile')).html())
```

Comment: so I need to make a div for $(somewhere) and change id to class ?

Comment: in my opinion it's better yes, create a <div id="occupantContainer"></div> and use it instead of the somewhere selector. actually I think that it's better for you to read Jquery documentation before continue, otherwise you'll code without understand precisely what you're doing ;)

Comment: that is my problem I keep on reading some codes but still I dont know what to do and what is happening >.<

Comment: start from JQuery website, understand selectors, and try to understand the examples shown on the website, they are quite easy but you have to be patient ;)

Comment: wait sir It says `missing ;`

Comment: instead of $(somewhere) did you put $('#occupantContainer')?

Comment: here `$('#occupantContainer').append($('.divOccupantProfile').html());`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45886/discussion-between-alessio-and-newbie)

Answer (score 1):

Here i have made a sample for what you should find helpful

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"http://jsfiddle.net/#save id="txtnum" />
<input type="button" value="click" id="btnSubmit" />
<div id="divOccupantProfile1">Data 1</div>
<div id="divOccupantProfile2">Data 2</div>
<div id="divOccupantProfile3">Data 3</div>
<div id="divOccupantProfile4">Data 4</div>
<div id="divOccupantProfile5">Data 5</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div[id^="divOccupantProfile"] {
    display:none;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
var num = $("#txtnum").val();
    $("#divOccupantProfile"+ num).css("display","block");
})
```

[**`Demo Link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gG5Ly/2/)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this @Rex it will help me a lot